# Unable to access text messaging after updating to ICS

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, sms, motorola-droid-razr

I have a Droid RAZR and the stock messaging app just keeps loading forever and Handcent SMS crashes when I access it. I have tried to leave it be and let it load but nothing happens.

I would use SMS Backup & Restore (or another backup app) like I have in the past but since the messages don’t load the progress bar just says “NaN 0/0″ and does nothing. This is the only thing preventing me from doing a factory reset/clear data since I have lots of messages on this baby that I need to keep.

I'm not sure if the messages have already been deleted, but if they were, wouldn't the apps work?

This is just one of my many problems I've been running into with ICS.

Comment: Any hint concerning your activities between "it worked" (as I assume it did -- or you would not have "lots of messages to keep") and "it crashes"? Maybe phone rooted, and messed around with something? Not accusing -- just asking to figure out any hints...

Comment: The second it was updated to ICS I couldn't access text messages with any app. Handcent crashes automatically. Never rooted the phone or have done anything radical to it before, just installed the update.

Comment: I assume that was an official update -- so I'd contact customer care (in parallel to hoping for answers here). You may not be the only one affected, and maybe they already have some solution.

Answer (score 1):

I do know that if you have a lot of messages on your RAZR before upgrading to ICS, it actually will try to pull them all in again to the text messaging app. I have seen this with both stock and GoSMS on a Droid 4 and it did take a little while on my RAZR MAXX the first time I opened up the messaging app after upgrading to see all of my messages re-appear, as they first appeared as if they had all been deleted.

If you are getting the little circular loading symbol, then it is likely the case - for a couple thousand messages, it took nearly all day to load them all. Not sure why, but this may also be what's effecting you. I guess the only solution is to wait it out and see what happens. Hope this helps and good luck getting your messages back.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the exact same issues with my text messaging. I did a complete factory reset, wiped the internal memory and everything, and now it's working. Sucks because I lost everything, but at least the phone works now.